# How to clear clipboard data in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Safari using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing a website. I want to clear the clipboard data when the print screen button is pressed while viewing my site by using JavaScript or jQuery. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem. I successfully handled this in Internet Explorer.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check out this question.
It should have all the information you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: I would really like to know how you did this with javascript in IE maybe you could show some code?

Comment: @megaperlz, there is a window.clipboardData object defined in IE family browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot manipulate the clipboard with javascript due to security reason. But the common way is to use flash...

Read that. It is very complete: http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/